# Bash can't find ghc after reinstalling?

Tags: bash, haskell, installation

I just reinstalled Haskell Platform ([here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794168/haskell-cant-find-package)) and after reinstalling the Haskell Platform I get:

```
Drews-MacBook-Pro:Blokus-AI drewgross$ ghc
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ghc: No such file or directory
```

Any idea why? I suspect that this is something to do with my path or something like that but I haven't found anything weird yet. I can use ghc directly:

```
Drews-MacBook-Pro:Blokus-AI drewgross$ /usr/bin/ghc
ghc: no input files
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
```

And /usr/bin/ is in my path:

```
Drews-MacBook-Pro:Blokus-AI drewgross$ echo $PATH
/Users/drewgross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/Users/drewgross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin:/Users/drewgross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/Users/drewgross/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

what else can I do?

Comment: symlink `/usr/local/bin/ghc` to `/usr/bin/ghc`?

Comment: that sounds like an ugly hack and while I suppose it will work I would prefer to avoid stuff like that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `bash` shell caches paths to commands that you've previously used. Using `which ghc` won't show this (because it's external to the shell and just queries the `PATH`), but `type` is a `bash`-internal command that will reveal this situation, so `type ghc` will show something like

```
ghc is hashed (/usr/local/bin/ghc)
```

The fix is easy. Either start a new shell (where you start from scratch), or clear the cache by saying `hash -r`.

Answer (score 1):

One of your directories in your `$PATH` has an executable symlink which points to the no-longer-existent `/usr/local/bin/ghc`. To find out, type `which ghc` in bash. If the result is indeed a symlink, simply delete it. If it's a custom script, you may want to rename it instead of deleting in case you happen to need it later.

Comment: The essential command is `type ghc`. Your shell might have the old `ghc` path cached. In `bash`, you can either do `hash -r` to clear the cache. Or you can start a new shell.

Comment: @kosmikus that solved my problem, thank you! If you want to make that an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Drew Glad that it solved your problem. I've added an answer.